# confusion between verb and noun

Tags: verbs, nouns

[image: can anyone pls explain me why the answer is expertise why not experts as i believe the answer should be experts]

Can anyone please explain to me why the answer is expertise? Why not experts, as I believe the answer should be experts?

Comment: The Conservators **are** the experts: they are the people have the expertise in a wide range of disciplines.

Comment: If you were going to say '...with experts in...' you would have to say '...a _conservation department_ with experts in...'.